# What is a "basis of identity neighbourhoods"?

Tags: algebraic-topology

What exactly is meant by the term "basis of identity neighbourhoods" in Theorem 3.1  of https://wiki.epfl.ch/std/documents/std_3_maxime.pdf ? Is it simply a basis neighbour of the identity or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. In the group-topologies it is enough to know such a basis th know the basis of neighbourhoods of any point, the rest is done by translations. Indeed, if $U$ is a neighbourhood of identity, then $xU=\{xu:u\in U\}$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. Conversely, if $V$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, then $x^{-1}V$ is a neighbourhood of identity. I have used the multiplicative notation here.